# How to know my latest operating system update on my mac

Tags: macos, operating-system

I cannot remember when I upgraded my mac PC operating system to Mojava, can I find that on my mac?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the `System Information.app`, there you will find a `Software` section and `Installations`, then search for the MacOS version you are looking for, you should see the date its was installed

[image: System Information]